# Yii2 выбор города с подтягиванием области в поиске?

Tags: yii2

Всем привет

В поиске инпуте когда юзер ищет свой город должно подтягиваться область, потому что сам город находится в разных областях.
Как сделать как на скриншоте??? Сейчас я использую [виджет](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/typeahead) от картика , там у меня просто подтягивается все города!

У меня список исполнителей и они выбрали свой город и свою область и сохранили в таблицу cabinet, и когда обычный пользователь хочет найти исполнителя по категории и по городу, должно подставляться область, что бы потом можно было правильно ему найти тех исполнителей которых он выбрал той категории.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там на демо странице есть пример `Select Repository` с кастомными темплейтами

Comment: там вообще не так

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант:

```
echo Typeahead::widget([
'name' => 'city',
'id' => 'cityTypeahead',
'scrollable' => true,
'dataset' => [
    [
        'display' => 'Наименование',
        'remote' => [
            'url' => Url::to(['city']) . '&q=%QUERY',
            'wildcard' => '%QUERY',
            'rateLimitWait' => 1000
        ],
        'limit' => 999,
        'templates' => [
            'notFound' => '<div class="text-danger" style="padding:0 8px">Ничего не найдено.</div>',
        ]
    ]
],
'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true, 'minLength' => 4, 'val' => ''],
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Введите название города...'],
]);
```

В контроллере:

```
public function actionCity($q)
{
    $cities = City::find()->filterWhere(['like', 'city_name', $q])->asArray()->all();

    return ArrayHelper::getColumn($cities, function ($element) {
       return $element['city_name'] . ', ' . $element['city_region'];
    });
}
```

Если нужно искать и по региону тоже, добавить orWhere в запрос.

Ну и как ответили в комментариях можно использовать datumTokenizer для построения более сложных схем.

Comment: Привет, у меня не много другая структура бд с городами и областями.

region_city:
id | parent_id | name_ru | alias

Область у меня parent_id = 0, а города parent_id = берут id от области

Comment: Так меняйте под ваш случай как вам необходимо, этот кейс абстрактный, поля условные придумал.

Comment: я не могу правильно сформировать, вы не поможете?

Comment: Я не знаю как у вас называются модели, как организованы связи, вряд ли за вас кто-то будет решать полностью задачу. Обратитесь на yiiframework.ru с полным описанием, там помогут.

Comment: мне надо тут правильную выборку сделать
$cities = ArrayHelper::map(RegionCity::find()
            ->filterWhere(['like', 'name_ru', $q])
            ->where(['not', ['parent_id' => 0]])
            ->asArray()
            ->all(), 'id', 'name_ru');

        return ArrayHelper::getColumn($cities, function ($element) {
            return $element['name_ru'] . ', ' . $element['name_ru'];
        });